# not able to display caldroid calendar on screen. what should be xml looks like for same?

Tags: android, caldroid

I am new to android and looking for caldroid calendar view. Can anyone one share me sample xml and source code to see caldroid calendar? Or may be some pointer link. I tried https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/issues/128 but not able to find source for xml like how to start with xml.